# Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, android

Всем добрый вечер, в процессе проекта у меня возникла потребность работать с архивами через ZipFile
Вообщем, суть проблемы заключается в том,что всё прекрасно работает на Android 8-10 , но, не работает под Android 5.1 - 6.

```
new ZipFile(archive, CP866);
```

Судя по ошибке и найденной мной документации, ZipFile отсутствует в Android ранее чем в Android 7.0

Какие могут быть решения? Альтернативы ZipFile на Android 6 и ниже ? Прошу помочь,спасибо.

Comment: Отсутствует не класс, а именно конструктор с указанием кодировки. Можете использовать другой конструктор везде или обернуть в `if-else`. Либо подключить стороннюю библиотеку, которая будет работать везде одинаково (теоретически).

Comment: Какие есть альтернативные конструкторы ? Пока не смог найти информации касательно этого, сторонние библеотеки подключать не желательно, лишь в крайнем случае.

Comment: А документацию смотреть не пробовали? https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipFile#public-constructors Обращайте внимание на указание `Added in API level` в описании

Comment: Спасибо,но.. у меня возникает проблема, ибо в архивах могут иметься файлы с нестандартным типом кодировки, который может нарушить процесс распаковки.

Comment: Ну если архивы проблемные, тогда только сторонние решения - стоковый zip.io гарантированно распаковывает только то, что сам же и запаковал.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, буду думать.